# SetVariable for a form's flash shockwave object from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, flash

I need help, what I'm trying to do is make it that as soon as the button is clicked on form2, it sets the variable for the flash shockwave object on form1.

form1:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

form2:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axShockwaveFlash1.SetVariable("_level1.shellContainer.ENGINE.my_room_movieclips.block_mc._x", "-5000");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should get back to whoever wrote the swf and have them give you something that exposes a method at the top level so you don't need so much intimate knowledge of its structure. This is just nasty!

Comment: @JustinPihony I want it that as soon as I click the button on form2, it sets the variable for the flash shockwave object on form1..

Comment: @user3061556 Without more code, it looks like you are already doing that? So, I ask more concisely, why is what you are doing not working?

Comment: @JustinPihony It says that "axShockwaveFlash1" is not in the form, so it can't set the variable for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static variable like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  VARIABLETYPE axShockwaveFlash1;
  ...
}
```

This will allow you to access the shockwave object from any object, but is global at this point and potentially dangerous.

Alternatively, you could use the [`ParentForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Form1.cs

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show(this);
```

Form2.cs

```
(ParentForm as Form1).axShockwaveFlash1....
```